# create edit button to GridView which edit item as a form in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i know asp Gridview is possible to create edit row function, so i have created it by following the [post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/edit-and-update-record-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net/) and i am success to do that.

However, i don't want to edit the item inside the table, but i want to edit it in a form. The form should bee pop up as a dialog which contains the detail of the selected item. After user clicks the save button in the form, the table will call `GridView1_RowUpdating()` to update.

So, the questions are:

> 1) how can i get the detail of the selected item to place to the form?
>
> 2) how can i call GridView1_RowUpdating when user click save in the
>   form?

any idea?

code for creating gridview:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="6" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"   

OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">  
            <Columns>  
                <asp:TemplateField>  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_Update" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update"/>  
                        <asp:Button ID="btn_Cancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel"/>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>  
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_ID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>  
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">  
                    <ItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>  
                    </ItemTemplate>  
                    <EditItemTemplate>  
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                    </EditItemTemplate>  
                </asp:TemplateField>  
            </Columns>  
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code for filling data to gridview

```
        var table= new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin");
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel");
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine");
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent");
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin");

             GridViewWait.Visible = true;
             GridViewWait.DataSource = waitDT;
             GridViewWait.DataBind();
```

Comment: You need something like this: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-GridView-Row-details-inside-jQuery-Dialog-Modal-Popup-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: @AT-2016 so, how can i call GridView1_RowUpdating when user click save in the form?

Comment: I am quite not sure if you can do it in the GridView_RowUpdating. You can use extra button to do so.

Comment: @AT-2016 what do you mean of extra button? Are you talking about the user click save inside the form, then click update in the GridView?

Comment: Yes. You'll probably need that if you want to do so.

Comment: @AT-2016 o no. It is a very bad user experience with extra step and they may think the data is lost when they click the first button because they don't know the existing of the second approval.